# TWUI : replace view with effect

Tags: cocoa, twui

Is there a way to replace a [TWUI](https://github.com/twitter/twui) View by another one with a nice transition?

I was looking for something like replaceSubView by View but found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this example by @joshaber that shows how to accomplish this using `TwUI`.

https://github.com/joshaber/TwUIPushPopTest